# Shell script display text in between two strings

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to make a script which takes two parameters, the first one is a number and the second one is a list of strings/files.

```
listfile 3 test.txt test1.txt test2.txt
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is put the file names under 2 strings `<h>` and `</h>`. Like this:

```
<h>
test.txt
test1.txt
test2.txt
</h>
```

The amount of stuff that can go inside that is determined by the first argument which for the above example is 3.

Another example would be if I run something like:

```
  listfile 1 test.txt test1.txt test2.txt
```

In this case each `<h></h>` can hold 1 file. so the output would look something like this:

```
<h>
test.txt
</h>
<h>
test1.txt
</h>
<h>
test2.txt
</h>
```

**Here's my attempt:**

```
#!/bin/sh

value=0
arg1=$1
shift
for i in "$@"
do
    if [ $value -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "<h>"
    fi
    if [ $value -lt $arg1 ]; then
        echo "$i"
        value=`expr $value + 1`
    fi
    if [ $value -ge $arg1 ]; then
        echo "</h>"
        value=`expr $value - $value`
    fi
done
```

So far I got it to work but the only issue is that the last `</h>` doesnt seem to get outputted and I can't seem to figure out a way to fix it. If I try:

```
listfile 4 test.txt test1.txt test2.txt
```

it outputs but is missing the `</h>`:

```
<h>
test.txt
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

If anyone can give me a hint that would be really appreciated.

Comment: `value=$(expr $value - $value)` is more easily written `value=0`.  A simple way is to test at the end: if value is non-zero, print a terminating `</h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

value=0
arg1=$1
shift
echo "<h>"
for i in "$@"
do
    if [ $value -ge $arg1 ]; then
        echo "</h>"
        echo "<h>"
        value=`expr $value - $value`
    fi
    echo "$i"
    value=`expr $value + 1`
done
echo "</h>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are wanting to accomplish. You provide a set of positional parameters with a leading number, and you want to group that number of parameter between the `<h>...</h>` tags.

Here is a slightly different approach than others have taken. A check as been added to test whether your first positional parameter provides an even distribution of the remaining lines between tags, and provides an error if the number of lines isn't evenly divisible into groups of that number.

```
#!/bin/sh

arg1="$1"
shift
nargs="$#"
if [ $(((nargs - arg1) % arg1)) -ne 0 ]
then
    printf "error: arg1 provides unequal line distribution\n"
    exit 1
fi
echo "<h>"
for ((i = 1; i <= $nargs; i++))
do
    echo "$1"
    if [ $((i % arg1)) -eq 0 ]
    then
        if [ "$i" -lt "$nargs" ]
        then
            printf "</h>\n<h>\n"
        else
            printf "</h>\n"
        fi
    fi
    shift
done
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ sh outputh.sh 1 line.txt line1.txt line2.txt
<h>
line.txt
</h>
<h>
line1.txt
</h>
<h>
line2.txt
</h>

$ sh outputh.sh 2 line.txt line1.txt line2.txt
error: arg1 provides unequal line distribution

$ sh outputh.sh 3 line.txt line1.txt line2.txt
<h>
line.txt
line1.txt
line2.txt
</h>
```

**Note:** if you want to allow an unequal distribution of lines between the tags, e.g.:

```
$ sh outputh2.sh 2 line.txt line1.txt line2.txt
<h>
line.txt
line1.txt
</h>
<h>
line2.txt
</h>
```

then a few additional tweaks are all that are required. The following will allow all distributions - equal or not:

```
#!/bin/sh

closed=1
arg1="$1"
shift
nargs="$#"
echo "<h>"
for ((i = 1; i <= $nargs; i++))
do
    echo "$1"
    if [ $((i % arg1)) -eq 0 ]
    then
        if [ "$i" -lt "$nargs" ]
        then
            printf "</h>\n<h>\n"
            closed=1
        else
            printf "</h>\n"
            closed=0
        fi
    fi
    shift
done

if [ "$closed" -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "</h>"
fi
```